# How can there be a dot(.) in interfaces like Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler or Map.Entry?

Tags: java, interface

If we see the definitions like Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler or Map.Entry in oracle docs, they are defined as public static interface. Wanted to know how is that achieved or written internally by Java? Because when we try to create some customize interface of similar pattern, the compiler throws exception at the dot(.)!

```
public static interface Dot.Intf{
void disp();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of an **nested** type.

Like,

```
public class Thread {

    public static interface UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        //interface members
        void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e);

   }
}
```

And there can be a separate class which implements the Interface defined in Thread class.

```
public class ThreadGroup implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
      //implementation to the uncaughtException method.
}
```

While accessing, it will be `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){}`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. @Codebender

Answer (score 1):

It is called an [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) or [nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

This code shows some examples:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new A.B();
        I i = new A.Impl();
        C c = new A().new C();
    }

    //nested class
    static class B { }

    //nested interface
    static interface I { }
    static class Impl implements I { }

    //inner class
    class C { }

}
```

Comment: `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is actually an *interface* :)

Comment: @TheLostMind And an *interface* is a [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html)

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman- You shouldn't ask someone to look at the class file format and suggest an interface is a class. In java everything (including enums) go in that format. `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is a `public` *interface* inside `Thread` class. Try putting a `public class` inside a `public class`. I was merely saying that the word `class` could be replaced with  `type`. And NO, an *interface* is not same as a *class*

Comment: @TheLostMind The class file format should be named "the java type format" and ``Class<T>`` should be ``Type<T>``, but that design isn't my fault. Java refers to types with *class* but I'd prefer the word *type* instead. While this is the technical side of view, I generally agree that an interface is not the same as a class or enum.

Comment: Thanks both of you @BinkanSalaryman & TheLostMind. Out of your conversation, I got to learn something more.

Answer (score 0):

We can refer static Inner classes like that.
Example:

```
public interface A {
     public static interface B {
        void blah();
    }
 }
```

for referring B we will use that syntax.